# Find maximum gap rate in Smith-Waterman algorithm

Tags: sequence, sequence-alignment

I am now working on Smith-Waterman algorithm. I understand that by increasing the gap penalty, less gap will be obtained in my final alignment but I need advice on how to control the maximum gap rate (ratio of gapped character in the detected char)? For example:

Maximum gap rate: 50% 
Sequence 1: ABBBBC
Sequence 2: ABC

Final alignment: AB---C

From the total length of the detected char, which is 6, it will detect up to 3 gapped char as similar alignments. Thank you.